# Expression for defining letrec implementing little language in Haskell

Tags: haskell, evaluation, language-implementation, mutual-recursion, letrec

I'm writing an evaluator for a little expression language, but I'm stuck on the `LetRec` construct.

This is the language:

```
data Expr = Var Nm  | Lam (Nm,Ty) Expr | App Expr Expr
      | Val Int | Add Expr Expr | If Expr Expr Expr
      | Let Nm Expr Expr
      | LetRec [((Nm,Ty),Expr)] Expr
```

And this the evaluator so far:

```
type Env = [ (Nm, Value) ]
data Value = Clos Env Expr
           | Vint Int
       deriving Show

eval :: Env -> Expr -> Value
eval _   (Val n) = Vint n 
eval env (Add e1 e2) = Vint (n1 + n2)  
   where
     Vint n1 = eval env e1  
     Vint n2 = eval env e2
eval env (If e e1 e0) = if n==0 then eval env e0 else eval env e1
                          where 
                            Vint n = eval env e
eval env (Var x) = case lookup x env of
                      Nothing -> error (x)
                      Just v  -> v
eval env (Lam x e) = Clos env (Lam x e)
eval env (App e1 e2) = case v1 of
                        Clos env1 (Lam (x,t) e) -> eval ((x,v2):env1) e
                          where
                            v1 = eval env e1
                            v2 = eval env e2
eval env (Let x e1 e2) = eval env' e2
                        where 
                            env' = (x,v) : env
                            v = eval env e1
eval env (LetRec [((x,t),e)] e1) = eval env' e1
               where
                 env' = env ++ map (\(v,e) -> (v, eval env' e)) [(x,e)]
```

This is my test function I want to evaluate:

```
t1 = LetRec
    [ (("not",  INT:->INT), Lam ("i",INT) $ If (Var "i")
                                            (Val 0)
                                            (Val 1))
    , (("even", INT:->INT), Lam ("i",INT) $ If (Var "i")
                                            (App (Var "not")
                                                 (App (Var "odd") 
                                                      (Var "i" `Add` Val (-1))))
                                            (Val 1))
    , (("odd",  INT:->INT), Lam ("i",INT) $ If (Var "i")
                                            (App (Var "not") 
                                                 (App (Var "even") 
                                                      (Var "i" `Add` Val (-1))))
                                            (Val 0))
    ]
    (App (Var "odd") (Val 7))
```

Comment: What is your *specific* question?

Comment: I want to succeed in the test of t1 above. However, there is a error in LetRec that I solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that your test program is wrong.  You don't want to apply "not".  A number `n` is even if `n-1` **IS** odd, not if it **ISN'T** odd.  So, it should be:

```
t1 = LetRec
    [ (("even", INT:->INT), Lam ("i",INT) $ If (Var "i")
                                            (App (Var "odd") 
                                                 (Var "i" `Add` Val (-1)))
                                            (Val 1))
    , (("odd",  INT:->INT), Lam ("i",INT) $ If (Var "i")
                                            (App (Var "even") 
                                                 (Var "i" `Add` Val (-1)))
                                            (Val 0))
    ]
  (App (Var "odd") (Val 7))
```

Your `LetRec` case is almost right.  You've just written it to only handle singleton lists for some reason.  Also, you want to put the `letrec` bindings at the start of the environment bindings list, not the end, otherwise bindings outside the `letrec` will take precedence. Try:

```
eval env (LetRec bnds body) = v
  where v = eval env' body
        env' = [(n, eval env' e) | ((n,_),e) <- bnds] ++ env
```

Here is the complete program.  When run, it should print `Vint 1`:

```
type Nm = String
data Ty = INT | Ty :-> Ty
  deriving (Show)

data Expr = Var Nm  | Lam (Nm,Ty) Expr | App Expr Expr
          | Val Int | Add Expr Expr | If Expr Expr Expr
          | Let Nm Expr Expr
          | LetRec [((Nm,Ty),Expr)] Expr
          deriving (Show)

type Env = [ (Nm, Value) ]
data Value = Clos Env Expr
           | Vint Int
       deriving (Show)

eval :: Env -> Expr -> Value
eval _   (Val n) = Vint n
eval env (Add e1 e2) = Vint (n1 + n2)
  where
    Vint n1 = eval env e1
    Vint n2 = eval env e2
eval env (If e e1 e0) = if n==0 then eval env e0 else eval env e1
  where
    Vint n = eval env e
eval env (Var x) = case lookup x env of
  Nothing -> error (x ++ " not defined")
  Just v  -> v
eval env e@(Lam _ _) = Clos env e
eval env (App e1 e2) = case v1 of
  Clos env1 (Lam (x,t) e) -> eval ((x,v2):env1) e
  where
    v1 = eval env e1
    v2 = eval env e2
eval env (Let x e1 e2) = eval env' e2
  where
    env' = (x,v) : env
    v = eval env e1
eval env (LetRec bnds body) = eval env' body
  where env' = [(n, eval env' e) | ((n,_),e) <- bnds] ++ env

t1 :: Expr
t1 = LetRec
    [ (("even", INT:->INT), Lam ("i",INT) $ If (Var "i")
                                            (App (Var "odd")
                                                 (Var "i" `Add` Val (-1)))
                                            (Val 1))
    , (("odd",  INT:->INT), Lam ("i",INT) $ If (Var "i")
                                            (App (Var "even")
                                                 (Var "i" `Add` Val (-1)))
                                            (Val 0))
    ]
  (App (Var "odd") (Val 7))

main :: IO ()
main = print (eval [] t1)
```

Comment: Try again the way you wrote it, and I got an error in "Non-existent parts in function eval."

Comment: I assume you mean "Non-exhaustive patterns in function eval".  If so, you must be running code that's different than what you wrote above, because all the patterns are there (except if you try to apply a non-closure, but the error message would be different).  Try compiling with `-Wall` and read the warnings to see which patterns you're missing.

Comment: `eval _ exp = error $ show exp` must help you for now.

Comment: I tried. However, I got the following error. 

```LetRec [(("even",INT :-> INT),Lam ("i",INT) (If (Var "i") (App (Var "odd") (Add (Var "i") (Val (-1)))) (Val 1))),(("odd",INT :-> INT),Lam ("i",INT) (If (Var "i") (App (Var "even") (Add (Var "i") (Val (-1)))) (Val 0)))] (App (Var "odd") (Val 7))
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at <interactive>:34:14 in interactive:Ghci3324```

Comment: I don't use JupyterLab, so I don't know how to help you with that.  I've added a copy of the complete program that I used for testing.  It compiles and runs without error and prints `Vint 1` for me.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation!! I googled it and solved the Jupyterlab problem using the information